# binding [(ngModel)] to undefined value

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, ngmodel

I have the below [(ngModel)] resulting in an error since I am not getting any values from the backend,

```
   <input type="number" 
          [(ngModel)]="list.test[0]">
```

in the above example I am not getting any values for test array from the backend resulting in an error saying cannot read property 0 of undefined.

I tried `[(ngModel)]="list?.test[0]"` but that didnt help either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The angular 2-way-binding with ngModel does not support the safe navigation operator `?`.

There is still an open feature request for it:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7697

You can use this workaround:
`[(ngModel)]="list.test && list.test[0]"`

So with 3 inputs your code should look like this:

```
<form>
<input type="number" name="item1" [(ngModel)]="list.test && list.test[0]">
<input type="number" name="item2" [(ngModel)]="list.test && list.test[1]">
<input type="number" name="item3" [(ngModel)]="list.test && list.test[2]">
</form>
```

It is important to give each input an individual name attribute.

Comment: well I am getting 4-5 values and it needs to be placed in different input box. I still have to display them even if no values are coming.

Comment: so you have many inputs? and each input shows a value of the array?

Comment: Yes to make things simple lets say array has 3 values if I get an empty array I have to display a input box with no value.

Comment: So an empty array means one input (displaying no value)? 
And 3 items in the array mean 3 inputs (each displaying the corresponding item value)?

Comment: Yes, empty array mean 3 input box with no value

Comment: how many input boxes do you have? always 3 or another fixed number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203936/discussion-between-spierala-and-jay).

Comment: Hey Jay, would you be so kind to accept the answer? :) Thx